# Downgrading Stripe subscription & Resubscribing

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am subscribing through Stripe to our tool and have run into the following problem. All upgrading and downgrading happen immediately. We want to do everything according to this scheme:

When a customer upgrades a subscription, the subscription to a new one happens instantly.
When the client downgrades a subscription, he uses the existing subscription until the end of the period, and we re-subscribe him to a lower subscription and charge him for it as well.

Is that even possible to do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, the default behavior for whether the customer is charged immediately here depends on whether you are upgrading or downgrading to a Price with the same billing period or a different billing period. This behavior is discussed in detail [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing). So, for instance, with a subscription upgrade where the billing period does not change (let’s just say the quantity increases), the customer will not be charged for the upgrade until the following billing period, at which point proration items will be included due to the update during the previous period. If you do want to cut a new invoice immediately when the billing period does not change but there is an upgrade, then you can set [proration_behavior: always_invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior).

In terms of deferring the downgrade of a subscription, the best way to do so is to update the subscription to the new Price or quantity and include a trial period via [trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end) for the remainder of the current billing period. This will ensure that the customer is not charged for the downgrade immediately but the downgrade will take effect at the start of the following billing period.